# Remove non numeric characters from string having multiple float values using for loop

Tags: swift

I have a string having characters and float values in a list like let string = "12.1gh34.5abc32.1". i want to remove characters from string and result will be shown in array with float values. is there any solution for this.

Comment: You can using regular expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string using letters as the separator. Remove empty strings from the result. Map the remaining number strings into real numbers.

```
let string = "12.1gh34.5abc32.1"
let numbers = string.components(separatedBy: .letters)
                    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
                    .compactMap { Double($0) }
```

The output is:

> [12.1, 34.5, 32.1]

If you want to deal with anything that isn't a decimal digit or comma, you can replace `.letters` with:

```
CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted
```

Comment: Define "not working". You might need `flatMap` instead of `compactMap` depending on your Swift version.

Comment: You should also add '.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)' to 'string'. Otherwise a string with whitespaces (like "12.1gh34.5 abc32.1") produces only 12.1 and 32.1

Comment: Its work well but when i make space between string values then its not work properly. like 12.1gh 34.5abc 32.5.

Comment: Did you make the change I suggested at the end of my answer? It works just fine even with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collection `split` method and set `omittingEmptySubsequences` to `true`:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func notContains(_ element: Element) -> Bool {
        return !contains(element)
    }
    var numbers: [SubSequence] {
        return split(maxSplits: Int.max, omittingEmptySubsequences: true, whereSeparator: "0123456789.".notContains)
    }
}
```

---

```
let text = "12.1gh 34.5abc 32.5"
let result = text.numbers                // ["12.1", "34.5", "32.5"]
let nums = result.flatMap(Double.init)   // [12.1, 34.5, 32.5]
```